# Excel 2013 - Deleting a row based on a specific cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to work out how to delete a row in Excel 2013 where the contents of a cell begin with a number.

E.G. In column H I have multiple entries, some beginning with letters, some beginning with numbers. I want to delete all rows where the cell contents in column H begin with a number.

### Any guidance/advice would be gratefully received!

Ok, so i've created a little bit of VBA code which seems to work on a single sheet:

```
Sub Macro_01()
Dim L As Long, i As Long
L = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
For i = L To 1 Step -1
    If Left(Cells(i, "F"), 1) Like "[0-9]" Or Cells(i, "F") = "" Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'm trying to work out how to get this to work on all 284 sheets in the workbook. I've tried Do/Loop but it just runs endlessly (and stops responding). Because I know how many sheets there are, is there a simple command I need to enter into the code?

Comment: Your requirement is to test column **H**, but the code looks at column **F** ??

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got my columns mixed. It is actually column F I need the code to interrogate.

Comment: When you say `... Like "[0-9]", I *think* you're looking for where the first character in the cell is a number from 0 to 9, correct? And **not** literally "[0-9]"?

Comment: Testing it on a number of sheets seems to work without deleting any rows where the data doesn't start with a number. However, i'm happy to change the code if someone comes up with something better.

I'm having trouble automating it across all 284 sheets however.

Comment: Does your code work? Have you tried [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting#t=201706191439074867926) it to see where it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help so far, I think i've solved it:

```
Sub Macro_01()
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Do
Dim L As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
L = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
For i = L To 1 Step -1
If Left(Cells(i, "F"), 1) Like "[0-9]" Or Cells(i, "F") = "" Then
Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next
Next ws
If ActiveSheet.Index <> Sheets.Count Then
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Else
Exit Do
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this work?  (I'm assuming the code you posted in itself is working as you expect and just need to run it on *all* sheets.)

```
Sub Macro_01()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim L As Long, i As Long
Dim ws      As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    L = .Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        If Left(.Cells(i, "F"), 1) Like "[0-9]" Or .Cells(i, "F") = "" Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
Next ws

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Just loop through each sheet, making sure to reset the last row variable.  Then turning of calculation/screenupdating until the end.  Note if you have 200+ sheets this may indeed take some time.

Finally, make sure to perhaps run this on a copy of your data first, as you may know, you can't undo a macro.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've tested it on a couple of sheets and it works as expected. It doesn't appear to loop to the next sheet and automatically run, or am I missing something really simple?

Comment: @Deadite - Hmmm...what makes you say it's not looping on the next sheet? If you use `F8` to step through the data, set a break at the `next ws` line so the code stops after it runs on the first sheet.  Does it not then go to the next one?  Or does it just appear not to run?